# Using DB2 on Windows 10 computer with PIN instead of password (Azure AD accounts)

Tags: db2, azure-active-directory

I'm new to DB2 database. I installed DB2 Express-C on my local machine (Windows 10) to play with it, and I created a sample database.

If I understand correctly, DB2 uses Windows accounts for access to database. The installation created a db2admin user, but this one does not have access to the sample database. So my understanding is that my Windows account has access to this database.

So here is the problem. My company uses Azure Active Directory accounts, using Windows Hello to log in - that means, using a PIN to log in instead of a password (meaning my password does not work for login). However, if I want to connect to the database, I need to do this with my account's password. How can I do this? Do I need to create a local account on my machine instead of using Azure account?

Comment: Windows Hello or PIN is a option to sign-in in windows. You can switch the sign in option, if you know the password.:-)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT this is somehow disabled by my company, so it's not possible to sign in with password ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create a local-user on your workstation, and assign it a password, and ensure it is a member of local groups DB2USERS (and optionally) DB2ADMNS if those local-groups exist, that is likely to be the easiest option.

You may need to have Windows local-administrative rights to be able to perform those actions.

You can then connect to any local Db2-databases with that local-account and its password (regardless of how you sign-in to Windows).

If you allowed Db2-installation to create local user db2admin (and give it a password) then that local-account is also able to connect to local Db2-databases, including the SAMPLE database. So it's unclear why you write that db2admin account does not have access to SAMPLE database. As long as db2admin has a valid password then that account can connect to SAMPLE if all default settings are active.

Db2-LUW is able to integrate with Active-Directory provided pre-requisites are met and special configuration is performed, see documentation. But unless you have special security plugins for Db2, then any account that wants to connect to local Db2-databases will need a password.  With special security plugins, other forms of authentication are possible.

Comment: db2admin can connect to the SAMPLE database, but does not have rights to read data ...

Comment: That is not what is written in your question.  If local user db2admin is a member of local groups DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS (if they exist), then after successful connection that local-account will be able to access data *if all default settings* are accepted. As this is a separate matter from your original question, you should open a new question and *give relevant details* such as the exact commands/SQL you are using, and the exact result (error code, sqlcode, error message).  Don't ask new questions in comment threads.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Azure account login gives license to only one user to access windows account. If you login with db2admin in your windows you might lost azure account I am facing such issues.
Better to communicate with IT team of your company and ask to provide DB2ADMN right to your Azure login user. DB2 install properly but not able to create database permission/authorization issue coming.